# Nav bar dropdown on mobile Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my nav bar with bootstrap when using mobile devices (touch).

If I'm using a computer, the nav bar works fine, but if is a touch device the dropdown is hidden if try to select a option.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
                        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>

                        <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
                        <a class="brand" href="/webga/index/index">Inicio</a>

                        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
                        <div class="nav-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                        Cadastros <b class="caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/empresa/novaEmpresa"/>">Empresa</a></li>
                                        <li><a
                                            href="<c:url value="/empreendedor/novoEmpreendedor"/>">Empreendedor</a></li>
                                        <li><a
                                            href="<c:url value="/empreendimento/novoEmpreendimento"/>">Empreendimento</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/atividades/novaAtividade"/>">Atividades</a></li>
                                        <li><a
                                            href="<c:url value="/subatividade/novaSubAtividade"/>">Sub-Atividades</a></li>
                                        <li><a
                                            href="<c:url value="/responsavel/novoResponsavel"/>">Responsavel
                                                Técnico</a></li>
                                        <li><a
                                            href="<c:url value="/documentacao/novaDocumentacao"/>">Documentações</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"> Consultas <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/processos/pesquisa"/>">Processos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/subatividade/lista"/>">SubAtividades</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Legislações</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Documentos</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"> Solicitações <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Licensa
                                                Ambiental/Florestal</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Declaração de
                                                isenção de licensa</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"> Relátorios <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Lista de
                                                Atividades/Sub-Atividades</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Solicitações por
                                                Empreendedor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Solicitações por
                                                Empreendimento</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Solicitações por
                                                Atividade</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Estatística por
                                                Atividade</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Relação dos
                                                Usuarios</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Relação de
                                                Empreendedores e seus Empreendimentos</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"> Ajuda <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Informações</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="#"/>">Suporte</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown"> Sistema <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/usuario/alterarSenha"/>">Alterar
                                                Senha</a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li class="pull-right"><a href="<c:url value="/logout"/>">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't update to the latest Bootstrap yet, did you?

I wrote a blog post including a temporary fix for this issue here:
http://forwebonly.com/fix-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-ipad-and-iphone/

But when you update to the latest Bootstrap (version 2.2.2 or higher), this issue should be fixed, as you can read in their [changelog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/12/08/bootstrap-2-2-2-released/).

> Here's the rundown on what's new in this release:
>
> ...
>
> Dropdowns: Temporary fix added for dropdowns on mobile to prevent them from closing early.

Comment: Forget i did not updated the js so that why the problem still sorry and thank you very much for your time